# Como funciona herança com "Constructor property promotion" no PHP 8?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, php-8

O PHP 8 agora suporta *constructor property promotion* para declarar propriedades da classe nos argumentos do construtor:

```php
class Foo {
    public function __construct(
        public $foo,
    ){}
}
```

Ao fazer a herança sobrescrevendo o construtor dessa classe e **não** chamar o construtor da classe herdada assim:

```php
class Bar extends Foo {
    public function __construct(
        public $bar,
    ){}
}

$obj = new Bar('valor');
```

Como o construtor de `Foo` não foi chamado a propriedade `$obj->foo` ainda vai existir (independente do valor)? Pois a impressão que tenho é que ao não chamar o construtor não há oportunidade para a "promoção de propriedade" acontecer.

Comment: sim, vai estar a sua disposição.

Answer (score 3):

O propriedade `->foo` estará acessível, pois cada um pertence a um deles, no entanto `->foo` terá o valor `NULL`, porque simplesmente ao sobrescrever um método dentro do "método filho" será preciso chamar o método pai (equivalente ao "super" do Java e Python), no PHP é assim:

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    public function __construct(
        public $bar,
    ){
        parent::__construct($bar);
    }
}
```

Claro, isso se o seu desejo for passar o valor de `$bar` para o método pai, se o objetivo for outro então o faça apontando o valor que deseja:

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    public function __construct(
        public $bar,
    ){
        parent::__construct('qualquer outro valor');
    }
}
```

A questão é que simplesmente se a classe pai tiver a necessidade de sempre executar o construtor por algum motivo de "configuração" de valores, será necessário que a classe filha faça os procedimentos necessários com `parent::` para os métodos sobrescritos.

Vale também lembrar que se o seu objetivo é simplesmente algo como isso:

```
    public function __construct(
        public $bar,
    ){
        parent::__construct($bar);
    }
```

Sem que o construtor faça nada mais, seria apenas passar o valor na mesma ordem de parâmetros ou "parâmetros nomeados" igualmente, não tem porque sobrescrever, apenas faça isso:

```
<?php

class Foo {
    public function __construct(
        public $foo,
    ){}
}

class Bar extends Foo {
}

$obj = new Bar('valor');

var_dump($obj->foo); // exibe "valor"
```

Veja que passamos o `valor` na classe `Bar()` e ficou acessível em `->foo`

Answer (score 2):

Configurei um ambiente com PHP 8 e realizei alguns experimentos e descobri o seguinte.

Definir a visibilidade (*public, protected, private*) dos argumentos no construtor da classe gera 2 resultados:

1. Uma propriedade da classe é criada com o mesmo nome do argumento, *sempre que a classe é criada* (mesmo sem chamar o construtor);
2. O argumento é atribuído para a propriedade, *somente na chamada do construtor*.

Para chegar nessa conclusão usei apenas uma classe e criei uma instância usando *reflection* para não chamar o construtor:

```php
class Foo {
    public function __construct(
        public string $foo,
    ){}
}

$reflection = new ReflectionClass(Foo::class);
$obj = $reflection->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
var_dump($obj);
/*
object(Foo)#2 (1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  NULL
}
*/
```

Com isso é possível afirmar que uma propriedade definida através de *constructor property promotion* não depende da chamada do construtor e uma propriedade definida em um construtor sobrescrito sempre vai existir.

Comment: Lembrando que o comportamento de sobrescrita sempre existiu, mesmo antes de propriedades via argumento, já que a questão do problema do entendimento esta no que **"é sobrescrita"** e como ele funciona.

Answer (score -3):

Sim, ira funcionar. Veja a documentação oficial do PHP tem um exemplo bem parecido com o seu: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.inheritance.php